# How to parse stored output in variable, store result and trigger another script based on the result

Tags: bash, parsing, variables

I'm writing a script to run another script with parameters and store the output into a variable.
The output has multiple lines but I only need one single line containing one of four specific strings and do something based on which string was found.

I want to store the output from the command into $OUTPUT but unable to parse and get the required lines to run an additional script.

```
OUTPUT="$(script.php $HOST $PARAMETER)"
```

Tried a simple if statement below but i'm already failing with:

```
RESULT=$(grep "TEST" $OUTPUT)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$RESULT"
else
    printf '%s\n' "No Match"
fi
```

This is what I'm getting, where '-p' is the $PARAMETER when executing the script:

```
grep: invalid option -- 'p'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Where I'm getting the correct output with:

```
printf '%s\n' "$OUTPUT"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that value of `$OUTPUT` are interpreted as shell command line parameters in this line:

```
RESULT=$(grep "TEST" $OUTPUT)
```

try:

```
RESULT=$(echo "$OUTPUT" | grep "TEST")
```

Comment: Better to use `<<<` instead of `echo`.

Comment: Also the question is tagged with "bash", this way it is also usable with posix sh (like dash).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to avoid this error and do not thread strings like `-p` as parameters is to rewrite your grep line like this:

```
RESULT=$(grep -- "TEST" $OUTPUT)
```

Double dash tell grep this is the end of parameter and all the rest is threaded as data